# Preview line options for version 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Just installed Outlook 2013 -- In the "preview" line for messages, I want this to display only on "unread" messages, but not on "already read" messages.  You had this option on my old Outlook, but unless I'm missing something, now either you can have the "preview" line display on all messages or on none on version 2013 ??

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the top requests on `outlook.uservoice.com`. Vote for it if you want to raise its priority further, although Microsoft is for the moment quietly ignoring the request.

Here's the link:

[Bring back the "Show AutoPreview only for unread messages" feature](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/322590-outlook-2016-for-windows/suggestions/11377068-bring-back-the-show-autopreview-only-for-unread-m).